# Using second highest value in an ON clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing MSSQL view where I need to include a new join to the view. To get the correct record data I need to select the entry where the ActivityKey is the second highest (essentially the second most recent revision of the policy).

```
select 
...
from polmem a
left join polMemPremium wpmp on (wpmp.policyNumber=pf.sreference
and wpmp.lPolicyMemberKey=a.lPolicyMemberKey 
and wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey = (select Max(wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey) where wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey 
NOT IN (SELECT MAX(wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey))))
where 
...
```

But the above results in this error:

> An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Essentially the error is telling me I need to have the aggregate

```
(select Max(wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey) where wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey NOT IN (SELECT MAX(wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey)))
```

in a Having and then list most if not all of the columns in the view's Select statement in a Group By. My issue is as this is a view used in multiple places and doing what MSSQL wants is a massive change to the view for the sake of what I thought would be a relatively simple addition. I'm just wondering if I'm approaching this wrong and if there is a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are also paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Markdown also doesn't work in code, so adding the `**` markdown (to attempt to make it bold) creates a syntax error. You can always use a comment to highlight a specific line.

Comment: Also have a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). `pf` for `policyfolder` and `sa` for `SCHEMEACTIVITY` are good choices, but `a` for `policymember`, `b` for `POLICYACTIVITY` and `c` for `scheme` make little to no sense. `policymember` and `POLICYACTIVITY` don't even have a `a` or `b` in their names respectively.

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN`s don't really make sense either. *All* your `JOIN`s are `LEFT JOIN`s, but you *require* that columns from the objects aliases as `b`, `po`, and `pf` *all* have non-`NULL` values. It is *impossible* for a column to have a non-`NULL` value is no related row was found, so why are you using a `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try something like:

```
select ...
from .....
..........
cross apply (select 
               *
               ,row_number() over (order by wpmp.lPolicyActivityKey desc)
             from web_PolicyMemberPremium wpmp
             where wpmp.policyNumber=pf.sreference 
             and wpmp.lPolicyMemberKey=a.lPolicyMemberKey) wpmp
....
where ...
and wpmp.rn = 2
```

I added cross apply (that means there should be a policy in the table otherwise the rows will be excluded). You could put an outer apply and change the where clause isnull(wpmp.rn,2) = 2 or similar .. but it doesn't make much sense to me.

PS. It would help a lot us (and mostly you) if you format the code in a nice manner.

Comment: Thanks so much - this is what I needed. And yes, some of these views are indeed a formatting nightmare..